# Looking for recommendations on scraping specific data from this unstructured, paginated HTML website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, stringr

As the title describes, I am trying to extract data from a website. Specifically, I'm trying to extract **host susceptibility** and **host insusceptibility** data from [each of the species pages found here](http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/sppindex.htm).

These data can be found on individual species specific pages, for example for [*Abelia latent tymovirus* at its respective URL](http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/descr001.htm).

I am struggling to extract these data as the HTML seems to be very unstructured. For example, host susceptibility/insusceptibility always exists in node h4, but along with other varying headers and listitems.

This is my first go at web-scraping and I have been trying with the chrome plugin Web Scraper, which seems very intuitive and flexible. I have been able to get the scraper to visit the multiple pages, but I can't seem to direct it to specifically collect the susceptibility/insusceptibility data. I attempted using SelectorGadget to identify exactly what my selector should be, but the lack of structure in the HTML made this ineffective.

Any advice on how I can change my plan of attack for this?

I am also open to trying to extract the data using R's `rvest` package. I have so far been able to read the html from a specific page, extract the h4 and li elements, and clean up the line breaks. Reproducible code:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

pvo <- read_html("http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/descr042.htm")

pvo %>%
  html_elements("h4, li") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  str_replace_all("[\n]" , "")
```

Which seems to provide me with what I want plus extraneous data:

```
...
[20] "Susceptible host species "                                                                                                                                                       
[21] "Chenopodium amaranticolor"                                                                                                                                                       
[22] "Chenopodium quinoa"                                                                                                                                                              
[23] "Cucumis sativus"                                                                                                                                                                 
[24] "Cucurbita pepo"                                                                                                                                                                  
[25] "Cynara scolymus"                                                                                                                                                                 
[26] "Gomphrena globosa"                                                                                                                                                               
[27] "Nicotiana benthamiana"                                                                                                                                                           
[28] "Nicotiana clevelandii"                                                                                                                                                           
[29] "Nicotiana glutinosa"                                                                                                                                                             
[30] "Ocimum basilicum"                                                                                                                                                                
[31] "Vigna unguiculata"                                                                                                                                                               
[32] "Insusceptible host species"                                                                                                                                                      
[33] "Nicotiana rustica"                                                                                                                                                               
[34] "Nicotiana tabacum"                                                                                                                                                               
[35] "Phaseolus vulgaris "                                                                                                                                                             
...
```

From here, I am unfamiliar with how to specifically select/filter the desired information from the string. I have tried some `stringr`, `gsub`, and `rm_between` filter functions, but all attempts have been unsuccessful. I wouldn't know where to start to make this code visit the many species pages on the online database, or how to instruct it to save the aggregate data. What a road I have ahead of me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one trick.

You can get the index of

1. `'Susceptible host species'`
2. `'Insusceptible host species'`
3. `'Families containing susceptible hosts'`

Everything between 1 and 2 are `susceptible_species` and between 2 and 3 are `insusceptible_species`.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

pvo <- read_html("http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/descr042.htm")

all_values <- pvo %>% html_elements("h4 li") %>% html_text() 
which(all_values == 'Susceptible host species')

sus_index <- grep('Susceptible host species', all_values, fixed = TRUE)
insus_index <- grep('Insusceptible host species', all_values, fixed = TRUE)
family_sus_index <- grep('Families containing susceptible hosts', all_values, fixed = TRUE)

susceptible_species <- all_values[(sus_index+1):(insus_index-1)]
susceptible_species

# [1] "Chenopodium amaranticolor" "Chenopodium quinoa"        "Cucumis sativus"          
# [4] "Cucurbita pepo"            "Cynara scolymus"           "Gomphrena globosa"        
# [7] "Nicotiana benthamiana"     "Nicotiana clevelandii"     "Nicotiana glutinosa"      
#[10] "Ocimum basilicum"          "Vigna unguiculata"    
    
insusceptible_species <- all_values[(insus_index+1):(family_sus_index-1)]
insusceptible_species
#[1] "Nicotiana rustica"   "Nicotiana tabacum"   "Phaseolus vulgaris "
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Interestingly this isn't working for me. The ```which(all_values...```, and ```grep()```'s are producing character (empty)

Comment: Found the issue that was stopping all_values from being created (missing comma in ```%>% html_elements("h4 li")``` which should be ```%>% html_elements("h4, li")```. It's working now; thank you!